# The documentary about Grigori Perelman needs English subtitles (finished)

Tags: discussion

**EDIT:**

It is finished. The [new post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13221/the-only-documentary-about-grigori-perelman-now-with-english-subtitles). Watch it on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng1W2KUHI2s).

---

I want to write *English subtitles* for the [only documentary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlxocvKVOXg) about the original Russian mathematician *Grigori Perelman*, who proved *the Poincaré conjecture* and then refused a million dollar prize. I am going to translate it from Russian to English. But I need help with editing. There are no math terms in the documentary, it is for laymen. I need help to make my English sound natural.

PS: I know that it is a question/answer site. But I suppose one of the site's purposes is also to encourage collaboration between mathematicians in *popularizing mathematics*.

Comment: Please, let us known when it's finished.

Comment: @GitGud: When the draft is finished to correct it or the whole thing is finished to watch it?

Comment: The draft is probably good enough for me, but I'm in no big hurry. Either way maybe you should warns us about both? That way maybe people give you suggestions about somethings.

Comment: So, is anyone helping you? Or are we all just sitting around thinking somebody else'll do it? I would offer to, but I'm not sure I'd have the time at the moment.

Comment: @JackM: I've got two editors now (only one from this post). If there were one more, I could break the text in three parts, so everyone edits only one third.

Comment: Do your editors need to speak Russian?

Comment: You’re creating a subtitles file, right? So it is separated from the video, right? And by the way: Great, thank you.

Comment: @NateEldredge: No need to speak Russian, they edit English text.

Comment: @k.stm: Yesm, the file with subtitles will be separated from the video.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it's only with subtitles. This is a great idea.

Comment: I am so excited. I have so much respect for Mr. Perelman. How much longer @Graduate (without sounding too hasty)?

Comment: It is finished. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider putting the script in a source-control repository and hosting it on a service like Github or Bitbucket, or alternatively putting it on a wiki. Either option will make it easy for people to see the work in progress and easily submit fixes.

See also https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/289/do-you-use-any-version-controlling-software-methods-as-writers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.