# The only documentary about Grigori Perelman is now WITH English subtitles!

Tags: discussion

It has been a while since I asked for help in my [previous post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/the-documentary-about-grigori-perelman-needs-english-subtitles). But it is finally finished. Here I found four people that helped me by editing my translation to make it sound more natural. Their names you will find at the end of the film. Look forward to other project where we can collaborate for a common goal.

If you still find a mistake or for any other reason, write me at *mosceo@gmail.com*.

Watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng1W2KUHI2s

Read: http://www.scribd.com/doc/214887959/

.srt for the video: http://pastebin.com/bL1ccTQQ

Comment: Thank you!${{}}$

Comment: +1 for the effort. But I am closing the question as off-topic as it doesn't pertain directly to the running of Math.SE. And besides, I don't think this really needs any answering. :-)

Comment: Very nice. Also, that took a dark twist at the end. That documentary is definitely inflammatory in several ways.

Comment: Do you know the creators of the film, maybe you have their contacts? I would like to make a German voice over and if allowed upload the film to a large German mathematics youtube channel to reach more people.

Is this the title of the film: "Иноходец. Урок Перельмана", English: "A man following a different path. A lesson from Perelman"?

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV: The owner is "Россия 1" ("Russia 1") channel. Here is the link: http://russia.tv/brand/show/brand_id/9188
At the bottom of the page you can find out the names of the author and the director of the film.